# DNS lookup local - how does it work?

Tags: windows, domain-name-system

i have installed a server 2019 Active Directory with an DNS server.

[IP Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKn4w.png)

You can see my DC is the DNS Server (192.168.190.10). 192.168.190.2 is my router.

My question: why is it possible to lookup websites with their DNS name? as example, i can browse to www.serverfault.com.

for my understanding, it shouldn't work because the router is the gateway. i am little bit confused...

Answer (score 1):

The DNS server resolves the DNS names. The router routes the DNS traffic. The router does not resolve the DNS names.